# Default username and passwords are not accepting for Simple Invoices module of XAMPP

Tags: php, bitnami

I have installed **Simple Invoices** Module Version **2013.1.beta.8** on windows. When I tried to login with default creds **user@example.com** and **bitnami** as stated in [README.txt](https://bitnami.com/stack/simpleinvoices/README.txt) file, it is throwing error as username passwords mismatch.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the following details and which are working for me

- username: user@example.com
- password: *password specified during the
  installation*

[Installation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2JLj.png)

Answer (score 1):

During the install process, you are asked for an username and password (there is no password set by default). To access the application you must use the credentials chosen at this moment.

[image: Install process]

According to the readme you have shared:

> 8. DEFAULT USERNAMES AND PASSWORDS
>
> The simpleinvoices administrative user and password are the one that
>   you set at Installation time.
>
> MySQL admin user is called 'root', and its password is the same as the
>   Simpleinvoices administrative user password.
>
> The default MySQL non-root account used to access the
>   bitnami_simpleinvoices database Is bn_simpleinvoices, and its password
>   is random.
>
> For Virtual Appliances and cloud images you can check the default user
>   and password In the Bitnami download page. The administrator user is
>   'user @ example' and the Password is 'bitnami'

Comment: I haven't come across the above screenshot which you have shared during the installation process. But I have been asked for the password field without the username.